# Fluent NHibernate: create mapping that should let me create a query with two inner joins to the same table

Tags: c#, join, fluent-nhibernate

I have an Items table with ItemID as primary key

I have a StoreItems table which has composite primary keys StoreID and ItemID. The ItemID uses a foreign key reference to the Items table.

I need to create a query which looks like this (goal is to select items which exist in two stores)

```
select * from Items i
inner join storeitems s1 on s1.ItemID = i.ItemID and s1.StoreID = myfirststoreid
inner join storeitems s2 on s2.ItemID = i.ItemID and s2.StoreID = mysecondstoreid
```

How can I do the fluent mapping to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

untested. it selects the ids first then gets the items. It might be possible to combine into one statement:

```
var itemsIdsInBothStores =
    from i in session.Query<Item>()
    from s in i.Stores
    where s.Id == myfirststoreid || s.Id == mysecondstoreid
    group i by i.Id into g
    where g.Count() = 2
    select g.Key;

var itemsInBothStores = ´session.QueryOver<Item>().WhereRestrictionOn(i => i.Id).In(itemsIdsInBothStores.ToList());
```